# Issue with dynamically selecting items recursively with MDDropdownMenu - 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Can someone please help with the below error. MDDropdownMenu is raising an attribute error as below,

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Below is my py file & kv files. I am trying to dynamically select 1 item of the list in the other. For example:

Countries = [ 'Japan', 'Australia', 'Canada']

when Japan is selected then only states of Japan list needs to get loaded in the next list items and not states of other countries.

Japan = ['Tokyo','Chiba','Kanto' ]

Something similar to below suggested by @JohnAnderson, but instead of defining in the **init** class, i wanted to have this defined in another class, in my example below : Address class

[Write the MDDropdownMenu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66726828/write-the-mddropdownmenu-item)

My .py & .kv files are as below :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Address:
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_file('../Files/Myapp.kv')

        countries = ['Japan', 'Australia', 'Canada']
        states = ['Tokyo', 'Chiba', 'Hokaido']

        menu_items = [{"text": f"{i}"} for i in countries ]

        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=self.kv.ids.field, items=menu_items, position="bottom", width_mult=3,)

        self.menu.bind(on_release=self.set_item)

    def set_item(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        def set_item(interval):
            self.kv.ids.field.text = instance_menu_item.text
            instance_menu.dismiss()
        Clock.schedule_once(set_item, 0.5)

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

My Myapp.kv file is

```
<Address>:
    id: country
    MDScreen :
        md_bg_color : [102/255,153/255,153/255,1]
        MDCard :
            size_hint : None, None
            size : 300, 450
            pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            elevation : 15
            md_bg_color : [157/255,159/255,48/255,1]
            padding : 20
            spacing : 30
            orientation : "vertical"

            MDTextField:
                id: field
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                size_hint_x: None
                width: "200dp"
                hint_text: "Choose Country"
                required: True
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                on_focus: if self.focus: app.menu.open()

            MDRoundFlatButton :
                text : 'Submit'
                pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                font_size : 20
                text_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_release:
                    root.submit()

            Widget :
                size_hint_y : None
                height : 30
```

Comment: Try copying your posted files and running them.

Comment: Hi @JohnAnderson, I am getting this error now -> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids', but i have provided the field id in Country TextFiled right, is that incorrect ?

Comment: For your posted `kv` file, The `Builder.load_file('../Files/Myapp.kv')` returns `None`, causing the error you see.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, you are right. what is wrong with my kv file pls ? any idea ? I do not understand why i am getting a None value here. Can you pls tell me what changes i might need to do to have this implement inside Address class / Correct the errors?

Comment: Your `.kv` file does not define a root widget. You can remove the `<>` from the `<Address>:` rule and then an `Address` instance would be returned. Not sure if that is what you want. Refer to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html).